# <abbr> html tag question mark

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am using Angular Ui-Grid to display a table and have implemented the pager for said table.

It creates a `/` to represent "of" as in this example "page 1 of 4". But underneath is some strange marking and when the mouse hovers the cursor turns into a question mark as if to say "I have no idea what this is."

[image: abbr not working]

This is the markup that is produced:

```
<span class="ui-grid-pager-max-pages-number ng-binding" ng-show="paginationApi.getTotalPages() > 0" aria-hidden="false">
<abbr ui-grid-one-bind-title="paginationOf" title="of">/</abbr> 4
</span>
```

Anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: That is what the `title` attribute is for. If defined, it should contain the full explanation what the abbreviation means. Browsers will indicate this with showing an question mark. It is specific for the `<abbr>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the natural behavior of the `<abbr>` tag.

To remove the dashed underline and the question mark on mouse hover, add this css:

```css
abbr {
  text-decoration: none;
}
abbr:hover{
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<span class="ui-grid-pager-max-pages-number ng-binding" ng-show="paginationApi.getTotalPages() > 0" aria-hidden="false">
<abbr ui-grid-one-bind-title="paginationOf" title="of">/</abbr> 4
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by adding

```
.ui-grid-pager-panel abbr[title] {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: none !important;
    cursor: unset !important;
}
```

to css.